# Computing x,y,z coordinate (3D) from image point (2)

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

Referring to the question: [Computing x,y coordinate (3D) from image point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point/20969634#20969634)

If I have the coordinate Z of the point measured in pixel (not in mm), how can I do the same thing shown in the question above?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same question? I'm sure the other problem only worked because the height z was fixed.

Comment: I understand, my task is obtaining the 3D coordinates (x and y) of the center of a sphere and the radius of the sphere. So it's correct projecting the plane on my two points in order to set the coordinate Z to 0?

Answer (score 1):

The calibration matrix A returned by [calibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) provides the scaling factors, when paired with the physical dimensions of the sensor. Use the [calibrationMatrixValues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) routine to do the conversions. You can get the sensor dimensions from the camera spec sheet or (sometimes) from the image EXIF header.

Once you have the f_mm from it, it is Z_mm = f_mm / fx * Z_pixels.

Comment: I'm reading the book "learning opencv computer vision with the opencv library" and I'm trying to use the formula q=sMWQ, where q=[x,y,1] trasposed and it's known, s is the scale factor and it is unknown (it's my problem), M is the camera matrix and it is known, W is the product of the rotation matrix and the traslation matrix and it's known, Q=[X,Y,1] trasposed and it is unknown (it's my task). How can I calculate the scale factor "s"? 
I don't know if what I wrote is related to your answer, sorry I didn' understand your answer.

Comment: Ok, so I have to resolve this formula
[69a88b04c61001bf4e198abae39569e8bc3e81c2.png](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/69a88b04c61001bf4e198abae39569e8bc3e81c2.png)
where "fx" and "fy" are the pixel focal lenghts that you have explained above and "z" is the distance between the point and the camera, it's correct?

Comment: Re-edited answer to clarify. Please accept or upvote if you find it useful