# Convert pixel coordinate into world coordinate in OpenCv2

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, coordinates, tracking

My program is for object tracking.
I could object tracking and provide objects x,y with coordinates by moments method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAJgO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjj2L.jpg)

***I want to convert pixel coordinate into world coordinate in OpenCV2.***  I've already got rotation matrix(3*3) and Translation vector(3*1) by camera calibration and I know focal length of my camera.

Now, I defined as follows.

```
 CvMat *rotation = (CvMat*)cvLord("Rotation.xml")
 CvMat *translation = (CvMat*)cvLord("Translation.xml")
```

And this is the part of my program.

```
void trackFilteredObject(Mat threshold,Mat HSV, Mat &Birds_image){

  vector <Fruit> apples;

  Mat temp;
  threshold.copyTo(temp);

  // these two vectors needed for output of findContours
  vector< vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  // find contours of filtered image using OpenCv findCountours function
  findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

  // use moments method to find our filtered object.
    double refArea = 0;
    bool objectFound = false;
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
    int numObjects = hierarchy.size();

    // if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS, we have a noisy filter.
    if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS){
        for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
            Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
            double area = moment.m00;

            if(area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA){
                Fruit apple;

                // moments method
                apple.setXPos(moment.m10/area);
                apple.setYPos(moment.m01/area); 
                apples.push_back(apple);

                objectFound = true;

             }else objectFound = false;
        }
        if(objectFound ==true){
            // draw object location on screen
            drawObject(apples,Birds_image);
        }
     }else putText(Birds_image,"TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER",Point(0,50),1,2,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
     }
}
```

And drawObject(apples,Birds_image) is this.

```
void drawObject(vector<Fruit> theFruits,Mat &frame){
  for(int i =0; i<theFruits.size(); i++){
  cv::circle(frame,cv::Point(theFruits.at(i).getXPos(),theFruits.at(i).getYPos()),10,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
  cv::putText(frame,intToString(theFruits.at(i).getXPos())+ " , " + intToString(theFruits.at(i).getYPos()),cv::Point(theFruits.at(i).getXPos(),theFruits.at(i).getYPos()+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
  }
}
```

And I use these souse file and header file.

**Fruit.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Fruit
{
public:
Fruit(void);
~Fruit(void);

int getXPos();
void setXPos(int x);


int getYPos();
void setYPos(int y);

private:

int xPos, yPos;
string type;

};
```

**Fruit.cpp**

```
#include "Fruit.h"


Fruit::Fruit(void)
{
}


Fruit::~Fruit(void)
{
}

int Fruit::getXPos(){
return Fruit::xPos;
}

void Fruit::setXPos(int x){
Fruit::xPos = x;
xPos = x;
}

int Fruit::getYPos(){
return Fruit::yPos;
}

void Fruit::setYPos(int y){
Fruit::yPos = y;
yPos = y;
}
```

Could you give me your splendid ideas.

Comment: The rotation matrix and the translation vector estimated by the camera calibration process represent the transformation between the chessboard frame and the camera frame for the corresponding image. Using a single image and an arbitrary object, you will not be able to recover the 3D coordinate. If you know the real object size, you should be able to estimate roughly the 3D coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the findHomography function in opencv. It helps to find the transformation from one plane to other but only the 2D co ordinates can be found.
This link provides the similar example of converting the coordinates from image plane to object plane. ([Camera pixels to planar world points given 4 known points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769707/camera-pixels-to-planar-world-points-given-4-known-points))