# c++ opencv matrix inverse multiply another matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

Forgive me if this sounds like an amateur question but I'm having problem understanding the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point). The author declared a rotation matrix of 3x3 and a translation vector of 1x3.

```
cv::Mat rvec(1,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
cv::Mat tvec(1,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
cv::Mat rotationMatrix(3,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
```

And then later there is this operation

```
cv::Mat rightSideMat = rotationMatrix.inv() * tvec;
```

Can anyone explain to me why this works, when the shape of the matrices (3x3, 1x3) don't align? I have tried it out and it runs.