# OpenCV Calibration

Tags: opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am little confused about world coordinates. How can we find the origin of world coordinate system.
Origin of camera coordinate system is behind the image plan on the optical axis at a distance of focal length. but how can we find the origin of world coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the origin of the camera coordinate system which is at the centre of projection, the world coordinate system is not fixed and should be defined by you depending on the use case. The origin of the world coordinate system can be anywhere, independent of the origin of the camera coordinate system.

The transformation between world and camera coordinates is defined by the pinhole camera model. See [this](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~majumder/vispercep/cameracalib.pdf) for a brief overview of the pinhole camera model.

Comment: okay and how can we define the world coordinete system in opencv. can you please share any relevant literature.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point) question provides sample code in OpenCV to estimate the world coordinates of an object from its camera coordinates. However, I would suggest you do some research about the pin hole camera model and homography estimation before you start writing code as it would help improve your understanding of the problem. The resource I mentioned in the answer is a good start. Please accept the answer if it resolves your doubt.