# Equation to reproject 2D image point to 3D coordinate

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I had a similar situation like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point). Within the question, the user who asked wrote the following equation:

[image]

It seems to work *, but does somebody know, how to get this equation? I was not able to find anything like this anywhere else...

Thanks in advance!

*) I also guess I kinda understand the equation:
the left part is the ray coming from the camera and going through the image point, therefore on the right side the real-world coordinates have to be translated and rotated as if the camera would be placed in (0,0,0)... sort of? 
I just can't find a paper or anything to confirm the equation

Comment: pinhole camera with standard camera model. probably explained in the Zisserman (multi view geometry) and afaik the camera model is explained in the openGL documentation, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple pinhole camera model equation. I guess what you are looking for, at least partially described PDF: [here](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws09/robotics2/pdfs/rob2-08-camera-calibration.pdf). You can also google more math yourself using keywords: `camera calibration`, `pinhole model`.

[image]
[image]