# Rotation/translation vector incorrect

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, calibration, aruco

I calibrated a camera according to:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpointslist, imgpointslist, imsize, None, None)
```

which resulted in:

```
rvecs = array([[ 0.01375037],
               [-3.03114683],
               [-0.01097119]])
tvecs = array([[ 0.16742439],
               [-0.33141961],
               [13.50338875]])
```

I calculated the Rotation matrix according to:

```
R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)[0]
R = array([[-0.99387165, -0.00864604, -0.11020157],
           [-0.00944355,  0.99993285,  0.00671693],
           [ 0.1101361 ,  0.00771646, -0.99388656]])
```

and created an Rt matrix resulting in:

```
Rt = array([[-0.99387165, -0.00864604, -0.11020157,  0.16742439],
            [-0.00944355,  0.99993285,  0.00671693, -0.33141961],
            [ 0.1101361 ,  0.00771646, -0.99388656, 13.50338875],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Now when I try to get the position of a realworld coordinate [0, 0.4495, 0] in the image according to:

```
realworldpoint = array([0.    , 0.4495, 0.    , 1.    ], dtype=float32)
imagepoint = np.dot(Rt, realworldpoint)
```

I get:

```
array([ 0.16353799,  0.1180502 , 13.5068573 ,  1.        ])
```

Instead of my expected [1308, 965] position in the image:

```
array([1308,  965,  0,  1])
```

I am doubting about the integrity of the rotation matrix and the translation vector outputs in the calibrate camera function, but maybe I am missing something?
I double checked the inputs for the OpenCV's calibrate camera function (objpointslist: 3d coordinates of the center of the April tag Aruco markers, and the imgpointslist: 2d positions of the center of the markers in the image), but these were all correct...

Could one of you help me out?

I used this procedure according to OpenCV's calibration procedure:
[image]

**EDIT (2022/02/03):**
I was able to solve it!
Steps for solution:

1. Solve cv2.calibrateCamera() in order to get camera **intrinsics** (camera matrix) and **extrinsics** (rotation and translation vectors)
2. Calculate **rotation matrix** from **rotation vector** according to cv2.Rodrigues()
3. Create the Rt matrix
4. Use a known point (uv1, and its XwYwZw1 are known, 2D and 3D) to calculate the **Scaling factor (s)**.

**NOTE:** In order to get the right scaling factor, you have to divide
the final equation thus that you get [u v 1], so divide so that the
3rd element becomes a one, this results in your scaling factor:

[image]

Now that the **scaling factor** is known the same equation can be used to calculate an **XYZ coordinate** for a random point in the image (**uv1**) according to:

[image]

The crucial step in this solution was to calculate the scaling factor by dividing by the third element that you obtain in the [uv1] matrix. This makes that matrix actually [uv1].

The next step was to implement a solution to the **lens distortion**. This was easily done by using **cv2.undistortPoints** on the **distorted uv/xy point** in the image **before** feeding the u and v to the above equation to find the XYZ coordinate of that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial step in the solution was to calculate the scaling factor by dividing by the third element that you obtain in the [uv1] matrix. **I added an explanation to the original question**. As well as explaining the next step involving correction for lens distortion.

Comment: that scaling factor is somewhat arbitrary (result of applying the projection matrix) and *individual to every calculation*. you can't and **must not** reuse it for calculations involving other points. in fact, talking about it makes no sense, because scaling such that z=1 is often called "homogenization". this stuff happens in a projective space and that operation is actually the projection. the matrix multiplication before that just sets everything up for this projection.

Comment: further, you can't recover the 3D point from just a projected 2D point. it's always a line/ray.

Comment: @ Christoph I am actually only interested in getting the X, and Y of the RW coordinates, as Z can be set to 0 (calibrated on a flat plate). This represents a 2D to 2D transform.
The way i currently fixed it is according to these sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point
 and 
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46588/camera-calibration-and-extrinsic-parameters-for-perspective-transformation/46591#46591

As I'm a bit confused about your comments, what do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

`Rt` is just the transformation (rotation, translation) from **world to camera** frame.

You expected a **projection**?

If you want to project the point, you still need to apply the **camera matrix** (and then maybe the distortion coefficients to be precise, but let's not get into that).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out again! I was able to solve the problem. The main step involved finding the scaling factor and use that to find the XYZ coordinate of a uv image point. I editted the original question with my solution!